# Use different Post Title for the Loop and Post/ single.php in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WooCommerce for WordPress with the custom post type for Products.

I would like the Product Title which displays on the shop page/loop to be different than the h1 title tag on the single product page..

The title in the loop is a limited space to fit in without skipping to a new line...and i can shorten it to fit, but on the product page itself I need to put a "fuller" title..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use CSS properties to hide overflowed title text, please check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

You can set a fixed height of the title tag and add `overflow:hidden;` so it will not display the text which goes to the new line. `text-overflow:ellipsis;` add some charm.

To be more specific, add following CSS properties to the tag holding your title on shop page.

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```